# c# with asp.net google map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

Okay i been working on this for hours on end. I am unable to get a map to pull with data. I did have it show the map but now does not working. I am using linq and pulling from database. I wish i could zip my files and send but I will try to explain.  Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for apxdesign page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">      </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var geocoder;
            var map;

            function ginit() {

                var geocoder;
                var map;
                function initialize() {

                    //var mapdouble = <%=MapID()%>;
                    var matt = -34.397;
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(matt, 150.644);
                    var myOptions = {
                        //zoom: 8, 
                        //center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                }


                function codeAddress() {
                    var addresslookup = <%=gAddress()%>;
                    //var address = "9531 poplar hill drive crestwood kentucky 40014";
                    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {

                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location

                            });
                        } else {

                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
          </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="ginit()">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 400px">
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the code behind the page. It works until i try to geocode. Just map it makes but as soon as i add the other code it breaks. I do have the right variables coming over and i tried to manually add them also.

here is the coding page

```
 namespace WebApplication7
 {
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];
       // MapID();
        //gAddress();
    }

    public double MapID()
    {
        //string id = Page.Request.QueryString["ID"];
        double id = -34.397;

        double mapdouble = Convert.ToDouble(id);

        //Page.Response.Write(" here is the id " + id);

        return mapdouble;
    }


    public  string gAddress()
    {

        string newid = Page.Request.QueryString["ID"];

        double gid = Convert.ToDouble(newid);

        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var address =(from p1 in db.Customers
                      where p1.ID == gid                          
                      select  p1.Address ).FirstOrDefault();

        var city = (from p1 in db.Customers
                       where p1.ID == gid
                       select p1.City).FirstOrDefault();

        var state = (from p1 in db.Customers
                    where p1.ID == gid
                    select p1.State).FirstOrDefault();


        var zip = (from p1 in db.Customers
                       where p1.ID == gid
                       select p1.Zip).FirstOrDefault(); 

        string addresslookup = address +", " + city +", " + state +", "+ zip;

         //Response.Write(address);
        return addresslookup;   
    }
```

Comment: If I debug at address lookup i have " address, city , state, zip " correctly. At the moment i hard coded the variables so i can see if anything is working.

Comment: Can you at least find out where the problem lies? I can help if the JavaScript is broken, but I know nothing of C#, Linq, or Asp. I noticed for example zoom and center are commented out, I believe they are both required to display a map

Comment: I think the problem can be in this part of js code: var addresslookup = <%=gAddress()%>; Correct it using var addresslookup = '<%=gAddress()%>';

Comment: Okay i got it working by taking out the extra function and putting it all as one. I do not understand why it would work then. Also i did uncomment it which i did by accident and then i had to put "" around gaddress . If i put back in the function codeaddress on the design page it breaks. I am not sure why the design page does not like doing two functions .